# MeteorJS - How to prevent anonymous clients from Subscribing to a collection?

Tags: meteor, subscribe, accessible

I'm using `Meteor` to create a web application.

The issue I'm dealing with is that I have a collection named `Books`, *and I want it to be only available to the logged in users, and not for the anonymous users.*

This is what I do:

```
if (Meteor.userId()) Meteor.subscribe('Books');
```

But this is not the best solution, because anonymous users can still get the `Books` collection information by opening up their browser console and calling `Meteor.subscribe('Books');`.

Unfortunately this is the only solution I can think of so far. I've heard of Meteor's `allow` and `deny`, but they seem to only affect when users **insert**, **update**, or **remove** on a collection (not preventing users from **subscribing** to a collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the subscriptions to logged in users from the server side, as follows:

From [Meteor & Security: Setting the Record Straight](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-and-security/) by [Sacha Greif](http://sachagreif.com/):

> Only publish posts if a user is logged in:
>
> ```
> Meteor.publish('posts', function() {   if(this.userId){
>     return Posts.find();   } });
> ```

In your case you need to change `posts` to `books`, properly capitalized to match other code.

This will cause manual attempts to subscribe while anonymous to come up empty.